# My picture looks like recycled paper!

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm pretty new to blender, started making my first project just to learn the basics of the interface, but when I rendered my image on cycles render,it started showing these grayish dots and messed up shadows, it looked like recycled paper to me so it was the best term i found to describe it.

It may be just my stupidity, but I would appreciate your guys help.
As I said, I'm new to the community and ask for mercy upon me and my mistakes D:

my rendering:

[image]

Comment: you need more samples

Comment: You need to set the shading of your background to "smooth" if that's what you’re referring to by 'messing up with shadows'.
Know that the size of the lamps as set in the properties window has a direct influence of the size of the shadows in Cycles.